# AWS EC2 - run shell and connect with git

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2

i run a AWS EC2 Instance with a shell script, which pulls the actual git. Github changed to private token authentication. if I execute the shell I have to insert manually my user and password. but I would like to run the shell with a cronjob automatically.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/code/NLP
git pull
python3 main.py
git add *
git commit -m "raspberry pi run"
git push origin master
```

i am looking for a solution to insert my git password and username automatically

Comment: Is SSH authentication an option for you?

Comment: i am pretty new to EC2 , so may yes

Comment: This functionality is independent of EC2. Instead of using a private access token to authenticate to GitHub, you could use SSH authentication, which, because of its transparency, is more scriptable. You could deploy your public SSH key to the EC2 instance using ssh-copy-id or create a separate GitHub key pair for the instance and upload its public key to GitHub. Either way, when the script executes, it won't prompt for credentials.

Comment: ok. i created a ssh-key in my EC2-Instance and copied it into my git-account. but what I have to do next. if I use git push, it still wants the username and password.

Comment: ok i found this: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories

Comment: You additionally have the option to retrieve credentials, whether that means an SSH private key or user/password combination or other, from AWS Secrets Manager. Launch the EC2 instance with an appropriate IAM role that permits secrets retrieval and decryption, and use the awscli (or boto3) to retrieve the secrets.

Comment: Yes, you need to switch your origin URLs from HTTPS to SSH.

Comment: To Jarmod's point: At some point you may want to share this key pair with many instances rather than creating a key pair for every instance. In this case, you should store this key pair in a secret service such as AWS Secrets Manager and retrieve the secret during instance launch using the CLI. Not only does this give you a central place to store your secrets and make it convenient to retrieve them, but it integrates with IAM, so you can control which instances / entities will be able to retrieve the secret. Plus, all accesses to the secret are logged and auditable.